# [android][gradle] I've updated, and blocked my Android Studio and gradle, version 4.8.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

The result is the message :
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper'.
Cannot write to file '/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.8.1/libexec/bin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar' specified for property 'jarFile', as ancestor '/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.8.1/libexec/bin/gradle' is
not a directory. Cannot write to file '/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.8.1/libexec/bin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'specified for property 'propertiesFile', as ancestor '/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.8.1/libexec/bin/gradle' is not a directory.

Comment: on Mac OS 10.12.6, android studio 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : the problem was'nt Android Studio. The matter was with Little Snitch which denied connection to Android Studio !
Now, I'll be aware about the power of context.